# Strange keyboard issue Ubuntu 14.04 and Thiinkpad Yoga 14 (S3)

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

I've run into an interesting problem with the keyboard settings on a Thinkpad Yoga 14 (model S3.)  I have not been able to find a keyboard selection that supports the slash, pipe key (i.e., \ |) and the quote key (i.e., " and ')  Most of the selections (such as English US have the \ | key translated to < and > respectively.  The one one keyboard layout that I have found that has the \ | key working correctly, English (US, alternative international) then does't support the quote key (or more appropriate the quote key appears to be a dead key.)

Has anyone else run into this issue and if so have you found a solution for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop and had to examine the XKB files closely to find out what layout would work with this keyboard.

I found that configuring the keyboard as an Intel Classmate PC layout solves the issue with the pipe/bashslash key as well as the quote/dblquote key.

I have not found any issues with the keyboard layout since configuring it as a Classmate PC layout.

To configure the keyboard in the console, execute this command as root (or sudo): dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration

The keyboard can be found under the name "Classmate PC".

Note that the settings may have to be reconfigured in X for each user by choosing the correct layout from the system settings panel (in KDE, at least).

To reconfigure in KDE, go to input devices from the system settings panel and change the selected option for 'Keyboard Model'.  In KDE, the keyboard is listed as "Intel | Classmate PC".

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when using the `English, US, Alternative international` keyboard I can get `'` with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> and `"` with <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>

Alternatively I have used on-board (the on screen keyboard) to insert pipes and slash.

*These are just workarounds and not long term solutions*, since both are a little cumbersome.  I regularly need slashes and quotes and neither solution works for both easily.

My next step is to get a USB keyboard and use that...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Thank you Luis for your comment.

Op's question was "Has anyone else run into this issue and if so have you found a solution for it."

I answered the first part: yes, I ran in to the issue.

I answered the second part with the solution I had found thus far.