# Thinkpad Yoga 14 backslash (\) / bar (|) key not working

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, keyboard-layout, thinkpad

I've tried lots of times to do this by toying with files in `/etc/gdm3`, or editing every `Xsession` I could find with `setxkbmap -layout us -model classmate`, to no avail.

I've also tried the steps listed here: [Strange keyboard issue Ubuntu 14.04 and Thiinkpad Yoga 14 (S3)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572382/strange-keyboard-issue-ubuntu-14-04-and-thiinkpad-yoga-14-s3), and that does nothing either.

The only way I can make this work is by manually typing:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -model classmate
```

in a terminal after starting up.

The default `Xsession` script is supposed to look in my home directory for a file called `.Xkbmap`, which I have created with contents `-layout us -model classmate`, and that doesn't work.

running `localectl` at boot shows this:

```
$ localectl
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: classmate
```

And yet, whenever I attempt to type a backslash or a bar, I just end up with less than and greater than.

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
XKBMODEL=classmate
XKBLAYOUT=us
BACKSPACE=guess

$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'us')]
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the output from these two commands: 1. `cat /etc/default/keyboard` 2. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Done.

Comment: Ok, no ambiguity there. Wondering... What makes you think that `classmate` is the correct model? The default, which works in most cases, is `pc105`.

Comment: Is the single quote `'` and double quote `"` key broken too? Sounds like this problem: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Thinkpad-Yoga-14-Ubuntu-Linux-Keyboard-Problem/td-p/1844776

Comment: Another option to make your changes permanent was used here: https://askubuntu.com/a/826825/307523

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Lenovo webpage](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Thinkpad-Yoga-14-Ubuntu-Linux-Keyboard-Problem/td-p/1844776) which sounds like your problem you can use:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Then scroll down to `classmate PC` and select it:

[image: classmate PC keyboard]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP has already made that selection. But you answered the question I asked in a comment. :)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The OP used `setxkbmap`. I'm not sure it's the same as `dpkg-reconfigure` which is what the link suggests using. As per comment my keyboard is also PC 105.

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` is a way to edit `/etc/default/keyboard`, i.e. make the configuration persistent, and that file says `classmate` for the OP.